# Using help() on a string instance shows "No Python documentation found for 'x'"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program like this

```
>>> str1 = 'Python'
>>> help(str1)
No Python documentation found for 'Python'.
Use help() to get the interactive help utility.
Use help(str) for help on the str class.
```

even if I modify this `str1` with other strings I get the same output

```
>>> str1 = 'programming'    #another string value
>>> help(str1)
No Python documentation found for 'programming'.
Use help() to get the interactive help utility.
Use help(str) for help on the str class.

>>> tuple1 = 'hai'    # using another variable
>>> help(tuple1)
No Python documentation found for 'hai'.
Use help() to get the interactive help utility.
Use help(str) for help on the str class.
```

But if I use it like this:

```
>>> str1=''
>>> help(str1)
Help on class str in module builtins:

class str(object)
 |  str(object='') -> str
...
```

And one more thing I noted:

```
>>> str1='list'
>>> help(str1)
Help on class list in module builtins:

class list(object)
 |  list(iterable=(), /)
...
```

Why does the `help()` not doing the same as with other types when I give strings as input to it?

Comment: The `help` builtin displays the docstrings of objects. Those objects can be local, imported or builtin classes or functions. `list` is a class, so is `str`. But neither `Python` nor `programming` are.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I think the confusion here and the reason for the question is that the OP expected `help('Python')` to give the help message of the string class, similar to `help('')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`help()` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help):

> If the argument is a string, then the string is looked up as the name
> of a module, function, class, method, keyword, or documentation topic,
> and a help page is printed on the console. If the argument is any
> other kind of object, a help page on the object is generated.

So when you use a ***non-empty*** string, it is being treated as a name (the first part of the quote):

```
>>> help('list') == help(list) == help([])
Help on class list in module builtins:
class list(object)
 |  list(iterable=(), /)
 |  
 |  Built-in mutable sequence.
[...]

True
```

But when you pass an ***empty*** string, it is being treated as an object, to which you get the type's documentation (the second part of the quote):

```
>>> help('') == help(str)
Help on class str in module builtins:
class str(object)
 |  str(object='') -> str
 |  str(bytes_or_buffer[, encoding[, errors]]) -> str
[...]

True
```

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help):

> If no argument is given, the interactive help system starts on the
> interpreter console. If the argument is a string, then the string is
> looked up as the name of a module, function, class, method, keyword,
> or documentation topic, and a help page is printed on the console. If
> the argument is any other kind of object, a help page on the object is
> generated.

When you call `help(something)`, that `something` must be an object, module, function, class, method or a documentation topic so it can print its *docstring* (special variable to describe how to use stuff in python). Otherwise, its just nonsense.